# arguments did not match any overloaded call

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

i am using python and qt designer when i am working on my controller i have this error :

> File "/home/sabri/Bureau/PycharmProjects/PFE/Controller/Cat.py",
>   line 14, in **init**
>       self.ui.AddBtn.connect(self.add) TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:   QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(),
>   QObject, SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 1 has
>   unexpected type 'instancemethod'   QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(),
>   callable, Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 1 has
>   unexpected type 'instancemethod'   QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(),
>   SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 1 has
>   unexpected type 'instancemethod'

this is the first time i get this error , what's the problem ! 
and this is my code :

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PFE.Classes.categorie import Category
from PFE.Interfaces.Categorie import Ui_Categorie_2

class Window(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QApplication.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_Categorie_2()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.AddBtn.connect(self.add)


    def add(self):
        a = str(self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText())
        b = str(self.ui.textEdit_2.toPlainText())
        cat=Category(a, b)
        cat.save_to_db()
        print ("ajout avec success ")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please correct your indentation.

Comment: What is your version of PyQt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to connect a signal with its slot is the following:

```
{sender}.{signal}.connect({slot})
```

Considering that `AddBtn` is a button and you want to use the clicked signal your code should be as follows:

```
self.ui.AddBtn.clicked.connect(self.add)
```